# Override nav from master page using css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I put this block in a child ascx:

```
<style>
    #HelloStyle { width: 0px !important; }
</style>
```

Hoping that it would override my nav from my master page: `<nav class="HelloStyle">`

However, it's not working. The nav class is still applied in my child page.
Any clues as to what I am missing? I would prefer to work with CSS and not JavaScript to complete this, in case clients don't have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change #HelloStyle  to .HelloStyle

You are referencing it by # which is the ID, while you are setting the class only, which should be referenced by the "."

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of other method that completely wipes out that nav or makes it `<nav> </nav>`. This takes effect on styling only but if I have text in between it will not be removed. I have solved this in c# by putting a condition on the masterpage `<% if ( // dont apply for child of this type { %> original definition with text <% } %>` but I'm looking to see if there something more effective that can be used on the child to remove that nav. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You used the `#` ID Selector, to match a class you need to use the `.` class selector:

```
.HelloStyle { }
```